# SecKeyRawSign in MacOS not available

Tags: ios, macos, csr

I want to use the function SeckeyRawSign for signing a CSR in a MACOS application. How can I use this funcion to sign. 
When I use the code in a iOS application, it works fine. 
I use the code of https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr

Comment: In macOS you can use [`SecSignTransformCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398780-secsigntransformcreate?language=objc) and in macOS 12+ even more convenient [`SecKeyCreateSignature`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643916-seckeycreatesignature?language=objc)

Comment: I tried to use this but the signature still invalid. I need to port the next code: SecKeyRawSign(privatekey, ksecpaddingpkcs1sha1, digest, sizeof(digest),signature,signature_len). The signature should be in uint8_t

Comment: I *translated* the linked ios-csr code to Swift and both APIs work very well in macOS.

Comment: is it possible to share the code?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/cbaker6/CertificateSigningRequestSwift (it's not my repository). Actually it's for iOS but it uses mentioned `SecKeyCreateSignature` API which is also available on macOS.